# Grouping icons/ tools in Esri Expand Widget

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angular

I am currently adding multiple icons to an Angular based Esri Web Map.
My current approach is:

- defining the icon in app.component.html:

  ```
   <div
       id="flyToNextExtent"
       class="esri-widget esri-widget--button esri-widget esri-interactive"
       title="Go to next extent"
   >
       <span 
           class="pi pi-fw pi-chevron-circle-right" 
           (click)="_viewHandler(1)" >
       </span>
   </div>
  ```
- adding the icon to he view in my app.component.ts:

  ```
   await this._mapView.when().then(() =>{
       this._mapView.ui.add("flyToNextExtent", "top-left");
   })
  ```

Let's assume I would like to group multiple icons in an Expand Widget or and expandable icon... How can I achieve this?

I don't want to cover too much space in my webmap with tools, thats why I want to group them:

[image]